# Display all the selected text in filter in card visual PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, visualization

[image]

Hi all,

I have a card visual on the right hand side and a filter on left hand side.

When I selected more than one items in the filter dropdown list, I want all the selected text to display in the card visual.

Right now I'm only able to display the "First" or "Last" item in the dropdown list in the card visual. May I know is there any way that I can achieve what I want? Or maybe there is any other visual or trick that I can play around to display all the text selected in the dropdown list? Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this measure

```
Measure = CONCATENATEX('Table', 'Table'[Class], ", ")
```

[image]

Instead of using **", "** as a delimiter you can also define hard line breaks by using **UNICHAR(10)** as 3rd argument.